# Argument #1 ($config_factory) must be of type Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface, array given

Tags: 9, dependency-injection

I'm writing a new module for the community and I have this error and I'm not understand what's going on.

The error:

> Mensaje   TypeError:
> Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles::__construct():
> Argument #1 ($config_factory) must be of type
> Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface, array given, called in
> /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php
> on line 259 en
> Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles->__construct()
> (línea 20 de
> /var/www/html/web/modules/custom/view_mode_by_owner_role/src/Functors/ListOfNodeBundles.php)

My functor class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;


final class ListOfNodeBundles implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  /**
   * The entity type manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface
   */
  protected $entityTypeManager;

  public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, ){
    $this->view_mode_by_onwer_role = $config_factory->get('view_mode_by_owner_role.settings');
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
  }

  public static function create (ContainerInterface $container){
    return new static (
      $container->get('config.factory'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
    );
  }

  public function __invoke(): array {
    $nodes = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();

    $bundle_list = [];
    foreach ($nodes as $bundle) {
      $bundle_list[$bundle->id()] = $bundle->label();
    }

    return $bundle_list;
  }
}
```

My service.yml

```
services:
  view_mode_by_owner_role.functors_list_of_node_bundles:
    class: Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles
    arguments:
      - ['@config.factory', '@entity_type.manager']
```

And How I try to implement in a form:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Form;

use Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Form\BasicSettingsForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Configure View mode by owner role settings for this site.
 */
class SettingsChooseRoleForm extends BasicSettingsForm {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles
   */
  private $listOfNodeBundles;

  public function __construct(ListOfNodeBundles $list_of_nodes_bundles){
    parent::__construct($config_factory);
    $this->listOfNodeBundles = $list_of_nodes_bundles;

  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container){
    return new static(
      $container->get('view_mode_by_owner_role.functors_list_of_node_bundles'),
    );
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'view_mode_by_owner_role_settings_choosed_roles';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return ['view_mode_by_owner_role.settings'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $listado = $this->listOfNodeBundles;
    $role_list = $this->listOfRoles();
    $config = $this->config('view_mode_by_owner_role.settings');

    $form['choosed_roles'] = [
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#options' => $role_list,
      '#title' => $this->t('Role list'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('choosed_roles')
    ];

    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $config = $this->config('view_mode_by_owner_role.settings')
    ->set('choosed_roles', array_filter($form_state->getValue('choosed_roles')))
    ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }

}
```

I have read some questions, but I don't understand why I have this error.

Comment: `parent::__construct($config_factory);` where does that variable come from?

Comment: You never use a `ListOfNodeBundles` instance as function, which is when `__invoke()` is called. You should use `$listado = $this->listOfNodeBundles();` not `$listado = $this->listOfNodeBundles;`.

Comment: `ListOfNodeBundles` does not need to implement `ContainerInjectionInterface`, nor to have a `create()` method. That does not cause the quoted exception, but it is not how a service class is implemented.

Comment: also remove the last ","  after $entity_type_manager -- from public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, ) <<<-- that will break it too

Comment: The trailing comma after the last parameter is only allowed on PHP 8.0. For a module that could run with different PHP versions, it is better to remove that comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by how the service arguments are defined.

```yaml
services:
  view_mode_by_owner_role.functors_list_of_node_bundles:
    class: Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles
    arguments:
      - ['@config.factory', '@entity_type.manager']
```

That service definition is telling Drupal to pass an array as first argument for the class constructor, when its first parameter is type-hinted as `Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface`.

The correct definition for that service would be either one or the other of the following definitions.

```yaml
services:
  view_mode_by_owner_role.functors_list_of_node_bundles:
    class: Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles
    arguments: ['@config.factory', '@entity_type.manager']
```

```yaml
services:
  view_mode_by_owner_role.functors_list_of_node_bundles:
    class: Drupal\view_mode_by_owner_role\Functors\ListOfNodeBundles
    arguments:
      - '@config.factory'
      - '@entity_type.manager'
```